# How to change Eclipse default classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm new to Eclipse, and I'm surprised I can't find the answer anywhere: I want the files created by my application to go to the .bin folder. (and be read from). The program reads resources from the default package in the project, and also saves to it. If my understanding is correct, I want to change the classpath to .bin? How can I do this.

**EDIT:** When, for instance, I make a FileWriter and write a file to the harddisk, I want this file inside the .bin folder, not on the same level.

Comment: Do you want to change workspace???what is mean of change in classpath

Answer (score 2):

While creating your project, select `Create separate folders for sources and class files` in `project layout` section:

[image]

And in the next widget window, select the output folder:

[image]

Comment: Yes, and you can change it later in the Build Path properties of the project.

Answer (score 0):

by default, if your project is java project, then your classes will be there in the bin folder. to view the bin folder, go to navigator perspective.windows>show view>navigator

Answer (score 0):

I simply gave up. I don't think it's possible to change the runtime classpath with Eclipse, so I just changed my application to `getResource("bin/myFile.txt")`. and prefaced the loading of all .png files with `/bin` also.